# What are the advantages of differentiating type/tag names for a typedef in C?

Tags: c, types

Some code-bases use a different identifier for the `tag` and the `type`, eg:

```
typedef struct _foo { int bar; } foo;
```

Instead of:

```
typedef struct foo { int bar; } foo;
```

The differences are explained in detail here: [Difference between 'struct' and 'typedef struct' in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328)
*(note, this question is about C and the link is to a C++ question, so I'm making the assumption that the basics of that answer apply to C too, though this may not be the case or there may be some subtle differences).*

---

My question is:

What are the **practical advantages** *(if any)* of using different identifiers for the type name-space and the global name-space?

Are there strong reasons to do one over the other? *(under certain conditions)..*
or is this just a convention?

Comment: In the old days, the compiler wouldn't let you use the same identifier for both. That's been fixed. Legacy code still exists.

Comment: You refer to a C++ question, but your question is for C. Please clarify; C and C++ are different languages and have some different semantics.

Comment: @user3386109: Can you provide a reference? IIRC are different namespaces for `struct`, `union` and `enum` tags a legacy themselves.

Comment: @Olaf, good point (question is about C), clarified in the question too.

Comment: @user3386109, regarding **"Legacy code still exists"**, I noticed this in the latest Python3 code-base.

Comment: Advantages are you know the context of each name. However, as types are often written Camel-case, a leading underscore is forbidden, as reserved by the standard for extensions (therefore `_Bool`, `_True`, `_Generic`, etc.). In general it is a good idea to add the same prefix or suffix. Typeically you only use a tag if you need a forward-reference and use `typedef`s by default, though.

Comment: @Olaf Sorry no reference, only the memory of old compilers from the 1980's that generated an error if you used the same name for the tag and the typedef.

Comment: @ideasman42 Yup, legacy code is the bane of all programming languages. The world would be a much better place without legacy code :)

Comment: *(to whoever voted to close as opinion-based)*, Im asking for **practical advantages**, not for opinions.

Comment: @user3386109: Well, I wouldn't be surprised if these compilers were just broken; I'd have to dig deep in K&R to see if they already defined a specific behaviour. But you brought up an interesting point. (I also add a suffix for tags, but only use tags if I need a forward reference and `typedef` consequently)

Comment: @Olaf - sorry, totally misread that.

Comment: @user3386109: Tags and typedef names have been in separate namespaces since the 1989 ANSI C standard. You're unlikely to encounter a compiler that doesn't get this right. If you're stuck with a pre-ANSI C compiler, you're likely to have far more problems than this.=

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, there are no real advantages.  Struct tags and typedef names are in different "namespaces" (not `namespace`s in the C++ sense), so there's no real problem using the same name for both.

The declaration

```
typedef struct foo {
    int bar;
} foo;
```

is perfectly valid, and there is no possible conflict between the name `struct foo` and the name `foo`.  The struct tag can only appear immediately after the `struct` keyword.

There might be some slight advantage in some IDEs.  For example, if you use click on an identifier and use a feature that shows you that identifier's declaration, there could be some ambiguity; it could show you either the typedef name or the tag.  But since both refer to the same type, that shouldn't be much of a problem.

If you want to avoid using the name `struct foo`, preferring the typedef name `foo`, then using a different identifier for the struct tag can be a reminder not to use it.  For example:

```
typedef struct foo_s {
    int bar;
} foo;
```

can serve as a reminder to avoid the name `foo_s`.

Going beyond this, in my opinion typedefs for structure types are not necessary.  I would define the above simply as:

```
struct foo {
    int bar;
};
```

and refer to the type as `struct foo`.  I personally don't see much benefit in defining a new name `foo`, for a type that already has a perfectly good name `struct foo`.  The only exception is for an abstract type, where you want to hide the fact that it's a structure.  Type `FILE`  in `<stdio.h>` is an example of this.

On the other hand, plenty of good C programmers disagree with me on this point, and feel that it's worthwhile to define a name that's just an identifier.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though I think the second (**"Going beyond this..."**) part isn't relevant to the question.
Attempting to keep this Q&A non opinion based too, since its flagged as *Opinion based*, rather stick to objective differences.

Comment: @ideasman42: IMHO it's relevant because *if* you decide to omit the `typedef`, the question becomes moot.

Comment: @ideasman42: There is no problem with expressing opinions in answers. Indeed, the close reason you mention specifically says that "many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience". The issue is with questions that generate answers which "will tend to be *almost entirely* based on opinions" (emphasis added).

Answer (score 2):

There's no discernible advantage. In fact, it is probably a good practice to always use identical names for both.

The practice of using different names most likely has historical roots. And I wouldn't be surprised to discover that it originates from a glitch of some specific implementation (as opposed to being mandated by some obsolete specification of the language).

Comment: The first part is just your opinion. It should not be in the answer. And there are good reasons, see @KeithThompson's comment.

Comment: @Olaf: Well, yeah. The inclusion of the word "probably" kinda makes it sorta obvious that it is an opinion indeed. But thanks, Captain, for reiterating it for us in much more unambiguous terms.

Answer (score 1):

Advantages of differentiating type/tag names for a `typedef`

**Educational**: The concept of the difference of a `struct` name and a tag name are easy enough to confuse a student of C.  By using different names, examples are more clearly explained.

```
typedef struct foo_S {
  int bar;
} foo_T;

// legal
struct foo_S s1;
foo_T t1;

// illegal
foo_S s2;

// struct foo_T is not yet defined.
struct foo_T t2;
```

[Edit]

**[DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)**: The appending of `_t` in used by the standard to indicate many types.  The suffix `_t` is reserved by some OS for future types.  The result is that using *some* suffix/prefix becomes a C style idiom to indicate a name is a type and not a variable.  Example:

```
typedef struct point {
  int x,y;
} point_T;

point_T center;
```

Should code use `struct`, the suffix is not needed:

```
struct point center;
```

---

IMO, the use of same/different name for a `struct` or tag depends on the work-groups coding standards and goals.  As C allows either approach, I simple accommodate my group's standard (pragmatic vs dogmatic).

Comment: Right, this is the difference, but what are the advantages *(if any)* of exposing this difference? *(thats the question)*

Comment: @ideasman42 "using different names, examples are more clearly explained".  If the same name was used, it would be more confusing to express when `struct` is needed or not.  Just like OP's post used different names to express the question.